# Nested `source` commands in my bash script?

Tags: bash

I have the following setup

```
└── modules
    ├── main.sh
    ├── major.sh
    ├── sub-modules
    │   └── minor.sh
```

- and I have added the path to `/modules` to $PATH.

all.sh:

```
source major.sh
```

major.sh:

```
source sub-module/minor.sh
```

But when I run this I get:

```
-bash: /sub-module/minor.sh: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. This is how the `.`/`source` operator works.

From the [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot):

> The shell shall execute commands from the file in the current environment.
>
> If file does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by *PATH* to find the directory containing *file*. Unlike normal command search, however, the file searched for by the *dot* utility need not be executable. If no readable file is found, a non-interactive shell shall abort; an interactive shell shall write a diagnostic message to standard error, but this condition shall not be considered a syntax error.

So when you use `source file.sh` the shell searches in the `$PATH` but when you use `source dir/file.sh` the `$PATH` lookup is skipped and `dir` is assumed to be relative to the current directory.

To do this sort of thing (internally to `main.sh` or `major.sh`) you could use [Can a Bash script tell what directory it's stored in?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59895/258523) to find the appropriate absolute path to use.

For general use you are going to need to stick them all in `$PATH` or `source` them from absolute/etc. paths.

Answer (score 2):

Path lookups only occur on names that don't contain a `/`. Also, only the immediate contents of a directory in `PATH` is checked, not all its subdirectories. With `source sub-module/minor.sh`, `sub-module` must be in the current directory. You would have to add `/path/to/modules/sub-module` to your path as well, then `source minor.sh` alone.

You can keep that to one line if you want:

```
PATH=/path/to/modules/sub-module:$PATH source minor.sh
```

This only updates `PATH` for this single `source` command.

Answer (score 0):

In `all.sh`:

```
export ROOT="${BASH_SOURCE%/*}"
source "${ROOT}/modules/major.sh"
```

In `major.sh`:

```
source "${ROOT}/modules/sub-modules/minor.sh"
```

`$PATH` doesn't have to be changed for this to work. For potential `$BASH_SOURCE` caveats, see  [BashFAQ/028](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028) .